Dynamics 365 - I have created a customized BPF on Opportunity but I am not able to filter the Opportunities based on the process stages
Is there any specific setup needed to see the stages in filters? Also I would lie to add a column to the view and see those stages but if I add a "Process stage" column, it shows nothing. So I guess I need to create a new field for the stages or? Thanks for any help here...
I have read all possible guidelines but cannot find any clue ohw to add the stages to he filters

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
